# Load a byte string into a Flask Request() object

Tags: python, http, flask

I have a POST request with attachments, parameters, host, data, etc. that I receive as the raw HTTP request bytes. Is it possible to load the bytes into a `flask.Request()` object?

Comment: To store data associated with a request, store it in the so-called "g object": http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data